# Distribution of $\frac{S_X^2/\sigma^2_X}{S_Y^2/\sigma^2_Y}$

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Let $X_1,...,X_n$ and $Y_1,...,Y_n$ be independent samples of the distributions $X\sim N(\mu_X,\sigma^2_X)$ and $Y \sim N(\mu_Y,\sigma^2_Y)$

I want to determine the distribution of $\frac{S_X^2/\sigma^2_X}{S_Y^2/\sigma^2_Y}$

---

My attempt:

I already know that $\frac{(n-1)S^2}{\sigma^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}$ and I also have knowledge of the $F-$distribution which says that for $V\sim \chi^2_p$ and $W\sim \chi^2_q$ the distribution of $F=\frac{V/p}{W/q}$ is $F\sim F_p,q$.

So basically I can do following:
\begin{align*}
&V:=\frac{(n-1)S_X^2}{\sigma_X^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}\\
&W:=\frac{(n-1)S_Y^2}{\sigma_Y^2}\sim \chi^2_{n-1}
\end{align*}
Then,
\begin{align*}
&\frac{S_X^2/\sigma^2_X}{S_Y^2/\sigma^2_Y} = \frac{(n-1)S_X^2/\sigma^2_X}{(n-1)S_Y^2/\sigma^2_Y} = \frac{V}{W} = \frac{V/(n-1)}{W/(n-1)} \sim F_{n-1,n-1}
\end{align*}
Is that correct? Can I simplify further?

Comment: Right, but remember this holds because $V$ and $W$ are independent.